# C# Update dbf file

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a programm to edit multiple entrys within a .dbf file.
For now i successfully loaded the dbf file into the datagridview and i'm able to add rows to it.
The actual problem is, i can't manage to update the dbf file after i added the rows.
I tried a savebutton approach, but i'm not experienced enough to get it to work.

The next approach i tried was to update the table within the "add rows command", but then i get an "insertCommand" error.

How can i write it to either update the table on adding the row or via button / with saveFileDialog?

Thank you in advance

```
private void btn_LoadDB(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK) 
        { 
            string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(0, openFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\")) + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"; 

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr); 
            conn.Open(); 

            string cmd_string = "select * from " + openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.Substring(0, openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.IndexOf(".")); 
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd_string, conn); 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
            da.Fill(ds); 
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 
            conn.Close();
        } 

    }

void Btn_AddValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource;
        dt.Rows.Add(
            txt_CTRTYP.Text,
            //+29 more values....
            txt_CTRGROUP.Text);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(); 
        conn.Open();            
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Update(dt);
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Where's the [OleDbDataAdapter.InsertCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.insertcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) sql/CommandText part? And you don't need to call `da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Create and set a valid insert command and call the `OleDbDataAdapter`'s Update(dt) method.